# Read csv in Spark with skip rows

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to load data from a csv file to a DataFrame. I must use the `spark.read.csv()` function, because `rdd sc.fileText()` does not work with the specific data in file (there are invisible comma characters in the csv data, `rdd sc.fileText()` splits them). The csv file has a few rows to skip on the start:

```
Report <- to skip
Generated by YYYY-MM-DD <- to skip
Sessions <- to skip
<- to skip
Session of all hosts <- to skip
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 <- it is my header
tst1,tst2,tst3,tst4,tst5 <- my data start here
tst6,tst7,tst8,tst9,tst10
...
```

I want to have a dataframe like this:

```
tst1,tst2,tst3,tst4,tst5 <- data
tst6,tst7,tst8,tst9,tst10
```

I tried to use the map and filter functions, but it does not work properly:

```
.rdd.map(lambda line: str(line).split(','))\
.filter(lambda line: len(line)>3).collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find anything that let me skip a specified number of rows but I was able to accomplish the same result by specifying the schema then reading in the data and filtering off anything I didn't want to bring along.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StringType}

val fileSchema = new StructType()
  .add("column1", StringType)
  .add("column2", StringType)
  .add("column3", StringType)
  .add("column4", StringType)
  .add("column5", StringType)

val data = spark.read.schema(fileSchema).csv("s3a://aws-s3-test-bucket/jeremy/foo.txt")
data.show(false)
```

Which yields

```
+-----------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|column1                |column2|column3|column4|column5|
+-----------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Report                 |null   |null   |null   |null   |
|Generated by YYYY-MM-DD|null   |null   |null   |null   |
|Sessions               |null   |null   |null   |null   |
|Session of all hosts   |null   |null   |null   |null   |
|col1                   |col2   |col3   |col4   |col5   |
|tst1                   |tst2   |tst3   |tst4   |tst5   |
|tst6                   |tst7   |tst8   |tst9   |tst10  |
+-----------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

You can then filter off rows containing the data that you know shouldn't be in there, e.g. The lines you wanted to skip to begin with and the column names.

I'd suggest using the actual column names when creating the schema rather than the place-holders that I used `column1` -> `real_name_of_column1` to get the desired dataframe. I used place-holders in my example to highlight the fact that the column names I used when creating the schema do not necessarily need to be informed by the data.

```
+-----------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|col1                   |col2   |col3   |col4   |col5   |
+-----------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|tst1                   |tst2   |tst3   |tst4   |tst5   |
|tst6                   |tst7   |tst8   |tst9   |tst10  |
...
+-----------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```